# Problema ao integrar os scripts Jquery, bootstrap e Popper.Js no angular 6

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, angular, front-end

Estou com um problema ao integrar os scripts bootstrap.js, popper.js e jquery.js no meu projeto Angular. Já realizei algumas tentativas, mas nada resolveu até o momento.

Os meus scripts estão sendo incorporados da seguinte forma:

```
"styles": [
              "./node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss",
              "src/styles.scss"
],
"scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/popper.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"
            ]
```

Uma observação importante: O Css do Bootstrap esta sendo carregado corretamente e funcionando perfeitamente. Já tentei colocar um `./` para tentar pegar a referência do diretório atual.

Comment: Amigo pq vc colocou .js duas vezes? O nome da sua pasta tem .js? vc colocou "popper.js/dist/popper.js" não seria apenas "popper/dist/popper.js"

Comment: Infelizmente não, @hugocsl. O caminho é aquele mesmo.

Comment: Como vc esta usando sass se faz diferente para importar o estilo, veja minha resposta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O recomendado e seguir a documentação oficial:

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-include-bootstrap

Outra sugestão seria usar bibliotecas como [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home).

Answer (score 0):

tente o seguinte:

```
"styles": [  
          "src/styles.css",  
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"  
        ],  
        "scripts": [              
          "./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",  
          "./node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",  
          "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"  
        ]
```

**Verifique se os seguintes passos foram feitos antes**

Bootstrap tem dependência de Jquery e Popper js. Para instalar o Jquery e o Popper js, digite os seguintes comandos.

Para instalar o jQuery digite:

```
npm install jquery --save
```

Instale o popper.js com este:

```
npm install popper.js --save
```

E para o Bootstrap 4, este aqui:

```
npm install ngx-bootstrap bootstrap@4.1.1
```

Referência (Segundo Método): https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-install-jquery-popper-and-bootstrap-in-angular/

Também faça o seguinte: Abra o arquivo 'src/styles.css' e inclua, no início, esta linha:

```
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Isso fará que o estilos do BootStrap sejam importados.